# Using EntityType to get data that are not existing in other entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to make a form with select dropdown that contains data from *Users entity* and are not used in *Admin entity*

**Controller**

```
->add('User', EntityType::class, [
        'class'=>Users::class,
        'choice_label'=>function($users){
            return $users->getUsername();
        }
    ])
```

**Users**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $Username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
 */
private $Password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
 */
private $Email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isBlocked;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserDetails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $Details;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Offers", mappedBy="User")
 */
private $Offers;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $joinedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $lastLogged;
```

**Admin**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $User;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isDisabled;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $rightsLevel;
```

I want to avoid adding same user with multiple rights. I could prevent it with just merging so rights would change but I think hiding users with rights is better option.

Any ideas?

I know I should do this with left join with EntityType query_builder option but honestly I don't really know how to...

**EDIT 1**

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kYfk.jpg)

Comment: I don't think I understand how rights and users relate. Could you maybe add a small example to your question? Which users do you want to fetch/ignore? If possible, you could also write the plain SQL or a rough idea what you think it should look like and what results you would expect

Comment: @dbrumann edited, rights and users are not related, Admin table gets an instance of Users and rights are just column of Admin table assigned to user instance

Comment: I'm wondering now that I messed up with Users table and w/out column that will be map with Admin table my idea will not work

Comment: It might be possible, but it will probably be a lot of work. Are you able to restructure your entities and schema? If so, I would suggest looking at Symfony's Roles to allow for ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN to differentiate on the same class whether a user is an admin or not. Additionally you can use Security Voters to look into a user's attributes, e.g. rightsLevel, to determine whether a user (admin or regular user) has certain permissions. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: Yes, I'm able to and I'll do it tomorrow. Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a query builder with your EntityType to select users and specify that the label is the username.

```
$builder->add('User', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Users::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
]);
```

Comment: This is giving same resultat as I'm having currently. Please check edit what resultat I meant

Comment: So do you have a role column or something in your user ? Instead of just doing a standard query you could add a where('u.role NOT LIKE "ROLE_ADMIN"') or something

Comment: No, I don't and I figured it out that I messed up this in database but was hoping that it's possible to do something like "SELECT Users.Username FROM Users EXCEPT SELECT Admin.User FROM Admin"